# Differential analysis tools for cryptographic hash function

Tags: cryptanalysis

Is there any software tools available for conducting differential analysis test on cryptographic hash functions?
If so, suggest few of them

Comment: Cryptosmt (https://github.com/kste/cryptosmt). you need to model the hash core using sat/smt

Comment: another tool: arx based cipher ( https://who.rocq.inria.fr/Gaetan.Leurent/arxtools.html)